# Unable to compile c#.net project on archlinux

Tags: c#, .net, archlinux

I'm trying to compile and run a C#.net project on Archlinux, the project is cloned from Github,

I have already installed both `dotnet-runtime` and `dotnet-sdk` as mentioned on the official Arch Wiki.

The output of botht `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --list-sdks` is `3.1.108`.

I have changed the version set on the `TargetFrameworkVersion` to v3.1.108 to match the versions installed on my system (was initially set to v4.7.2).

When I run `dotnet run` I get the following error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.108/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v3.1.108 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my setup, how can I fix it and compile the project?

PS: when I create a new console project it compiles and runs successfully (using mono); the project that fails is Form.

Thank you.

**Edit: added csproj file**

Here is what my csproj file has:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{8002D96E-7055-4D1D-8FA2-5687CA8A217F}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>GestionVisite</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>GestionVisite</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.1.108</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="model\Personne.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="model\DB.cs" />
    <Compile Include="model\Geometry.cs" />
    <Compile Include="model\Helper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: dotnet (3.1.108) is .NETCore. Whereas "v4.7.2" is .NETFramework. They are different. See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: hey @user9938, thanks for your comment, the archlinux wiki is stating that .NETCore is a successor to .NETFramework. I also have checked the link you provided, and when I click on download they show documentation on how to install .NETCore and .NETRuntime, but nothing on installing .NETFramework, check this link for ubuntu installation for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

Comment: Show us what the project file looks like, but if there's a property called TargetFrameworkVersion then it's a full .NET Framework project and requires Windows to be compiled. .NET Core can be compiled on arch but you have to use one of the supported target frameworks in an [SDK style project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks). Windows Forms projects require Windows to compile on all versions of .NET.

Comment: @MikeZboray I have added the csproj file to my post, please note that I have tried running the project on windows too using VsCode but I was getting the exact same error.
Thank you!

Comment: `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` indicates that it's a WinForms project. Of course this can also be seen by looking at the following reference: `<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />`. According to  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework: "What is the difference between .NET Core and .NET Framework? ....NET Core is cross-platform and runs on Linux, macOS, and Windows. .NET Framework only runs on Windows."

Comment: You can run Windows on Linux using VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/ . Although you have to buy a copy of Windows.

Comment: @user9938 I now get it, thank you guys for your explanations.

Comment: You might post and accept your answer to summarize what you learned, or simply delete this question to end the discussion (in case some miserable answers follow).